# IIS Friendly Site Names over VPN

Tags: vpn, iis-7.5

I have IIS 7.5 running with users connecting to sites over VPN.  So far, I've been giving out links with the port number such as http://servername:8082, and under the site's bindings I've been leaving the hostname blank.

When not working over a VPN (e.g., on a public server), I'd set up a DNS entry to point to my server and set the IIS Site's hostname accordingly.  This way people can access it via http://example.com.

What do I need to do to configure these "friendly names" for VPN access?  I can't seem to find the right combination of hostname/address.  Ideally I could map the site http://mysite.servername (or even http://servername/mysite would be better than it currently is).  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your websites are running on ports other than 80 then you can't use DNS to direct the browser to the correct website.

If you need to do this then you should configure the sites to all run on port 80 and use Host Headers in the site bindings to direct the browser to the correct website. Then you just need to set up the appropriate DNS record for each website.

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance, but where would I set up the DNS?  I set them up on that server? (part of my confusion is that I don't have my usual domain DNS to work with like I do for public facing sites, whose DNS I've always handled from a separate server, so it was just a matter of adding an A-record).